# Is there a way that i can link a FTP account to apache2?

Tags: apache-http-server, ftp

I got a FTP account (not from hosting providers), it's from a storage provider, i'd like to know if there is a way that i can access those files using my domain, like a hosting provider, you upload your website files to the FTP account, and you can access the files on FTP with your domain.

example:

```
files.example.com/file1.mp4
files.example.com/file2.jpg
files.example.com/file3.html
```

Comment: You can make Apache serve GET requests from an FTP server using mod_proxy_ftp: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_ftp.html. It doesn't make much sense to do that though as it adds more latency and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Apachebis a web server and has nothing to do with FTP.

The FTP protocol does not recognise domain names, so it will be possible to set up your domain name to point to the ftp server and create ftp based URLs that will work in many browsers - although you will likely be giving up your security.

Step 1 would be to add a CNAME from a subdomain of your domain name to the ftp server domain name. (For example set up ftp.example.com to ftp.real.server.  If you need to set up example.com, don't use a CNAME, use an A record that points to the IP address of the FTP server)

Step 2 - sort out access permissions. I expect a username and password are likely mandatory as this is the way FTP servers work out what files you can see. If possible create a new user with read-only permissions - otherwise if you share the ftp URL you are "giving away the farm"

Step 3 - craft your URL - it will likely be in the form

```
  ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/path/to/file.name
```

Its not a great idea to use this for html or web browsing, although it might work after a limited fashion.